# Cannot find module's path alias defined in tsconfig

Tags: javascript, typescript

My application's structure is as follows:

```
myApplication
├── app
│   ├── api
│   ├── services
│   └── db
│       ├── index.ts
│       └── config.ts
│
├── test
│   └── helpers
│       └── setupTests.ts
│
└── tsconfig.json
```

and I've defined the following path aliases inside `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"],
      "@Api/*": ["app/api/*"],
      "@Services/*": ["app/services/*"],
      "@Db/*": ["app/db/*"],
    },
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "plugins": [
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" }
    ]
  }
}
```

using any of the path aliases in a file inside `app/` works fine but when running the app with the following import inside `test/helpers/setupTests.ts`:

```
import config from '@Db/config';
```

I get the following error: `Error: Cannot find module '@Db/config'`. How can this be fixed?

Comment: It is setup correctly ( the same setup works for me..). One dumb question, in the question you write this `import config from '@Db/config\`` which actually has a single quote `'` on beginning and a `\`` high quote on the end. That's not true for the file right? .

Comment: Have you tried clearing vscode resp. IDE caches?.

Comment: @SilvanBregy sorry yeah that was just a mistake. Have tried doing "Clear Editor History" in vscode but that didn't help

Comment: The <i>tsc-alias</i> version can be the cause of this issue. You could try to change the package version.